# Count(*) returns a value of 0 (even though it should be at least 1+)

Tags: hiveql

I have a table of users in S3 that I'm running some queries against.  In particular, I'm trying to get a count of records for a particular user ID.  I start by querying the entire table as:

```
Select * 
From table 
Limit 100
```

That works just fine and returns results.  I then copy one of the user ID's that I get from that result and run this query:

```
Select count(id)
From table 
Where id = 'abc123'
```

Since I copied the user ID directly from the table I should get a count of at least 1 - as I know there is at least one record for that ID.  However, Hive returns a result of 0.

I have tried analyze table to compute statistics and then re-ran my query and still got a count of 0.

So I then tried the following code but this timed out on me and wouldn't show any results.  It took the query 0.001 seconds to run but then it just sat there "loading..." the table and then I eventually get a message saying "Operation timed out."

```
Select * 
From table 
Where id = 'abc123'
Limit 100
```

Any thoughts on why this may be happening or how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run the analyze command? Maybe the data is not updated

Comment: @Milk I did.  I ran "analyze table xxxx compute statistics" and then re-ran my query and still got a result of 0.

Comment: It can be the issue with spaces in the id. Try where trim(id) = 'abc123' to check this hypothesis

Comment: @leftjoin Thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried that and it's still returning zero results.